# скрипт для открытия файла

Tags: php

1. Страницы должны быть доступны по адресу вида http://localhost/page/name.ext
   Тут name - имя страницы и имя файла, а .ext расширение .txt или .html
2. Если .ext = .txt - страницы должны показываться как plain text.
3. Если .ext = .html - страницы должны быть преобразованы в HTML.

Как можно реализовать подобное, никак не пойму. Если кто знает, подскажите плз. , очень интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Apache mor_rewrite( пишем правило чтобы, например, "переписывало" страницу вида  http://localhost/page/name.ext в http://localhost/page.php?file=name.ext ) + единый скрипт который и будет устанавливать необходимый заголовок и собственно отдавать необходимые данные... По поводу "преобразована" не совсем понятно...
Кстати насколько я знаю при открытии текстового файла plain/text устанавливается автоматически посему, откровенно говоря - не совсем понимаю зачем вообще все это нужно, но если таки необходимо - алгоритм я описал выше